# How do i customize the navigation menu in the mobile app for community?

Tags: salesforce1-app, customer-community, lightning-community

I have created the Lightning Component by implementing following interface

> implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"

Also Created Lightning Tab & added in the Mobile Navigation , hence i can be able to access the lightning tab in SF1.[image]

But if i logged in system admin in community, i can't be able to see the particular tab in SF1. How can i able to access the tab in communities(in SF1), also is there any other way i can be able to show the lightning component directly in community(in SF1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation for the Mobile Navigation setup page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=salesforce_app_customize_nav_menu.htm&type=5) in your screenshot:

> The navigation menu in a community isn’t controlled via the Navigation
>   Menu settings page. Instead, the tabs that are specified in Tabs &
>   Pages in the community’s administration settings determine the
>   contents of the community’s navigation menu.

Comment: i am not using Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce napil type. SO i can't see Tabs & Pages in the community's administartion page.

Comment: Really? I have a community that uses the Customer Service template, but still have a Tabs item in the Administration workspace, and the on-screen info there says "These tabs show in communities using the Standard Tabs + Visualforce template and determine community navigation in the mobile app."

Comment: I could only see Tabs & Pages in Tabs + Visualforce template. So i will try to make the changes to template and see. Thanks for your help.

Comment: i have a question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271386/cant-be-able-to-access-anything-as-a-community-user-in-sf1, can you please respond if you have some time?